# mysql - how to check the db-wide availibilty of an auto_incremental column?

Tags: mysql

After a quick search through existing questions I decided to ask the community:

I'd like to check the database-wide availibility of an auto_incremental value in every table. The columns are named with 'id' - can this be done with a query?

Don't know any approach how to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use special database information_schema.

```
select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME 
from information_schema.columns 
where TABLE_SCHEMA='your_database_name'
and EXTRA='auto_increment';
```